# Data structure for looking up values based on keys being in a range

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm looking for an alternative to a dictionary that will allow me to efficiently use ranges as keys. Presumably the data structure needs to be sorted - maybe something like a b tree? I haven't found a good python implementation.

For example, given the following dictionary-like data structure:

`d = {'38.1003827193': 'value1', '58.29932891733': 'value2'}`

Searching for the range `38 -> 38.337` should return `value1`

Comment: `collections.OrderedDict` (`ordereddict` in Python 3) provides a dictionary that maintains the order of keys in the order they were inserted. You might be able to build on this with a range access method. How large do you expect the data structure to get?

Comment: Are the keys integers, strings of any other basic data type? Should the dict keys be ranges or you just want to search using ranges?

Comment: The dictionary is likely to be on the order of 100k items. The keys are a string containing two floats separated by a comma (e.g. '23.29382398, 84.2390230'). The ranges would just be for searching. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The dictionary you showed can be efficiently(?) searched by doing something like: [y for x,y in d.items() if float(x) >= 38.0 and float(x) < 39.0]. The range values would need to be substituted with variable data in the formula.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [range tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your keys are kept as strings, but the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module in the standard library can help you do binary searches in a sorted index. Multidimensional indexing is another chapter in turn, and the primary question is how you use your data; trees may be faster for insertions or particular distributions, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but I think this is what you meant:

```
d = {'38.1003827193': 'value1', '58.29932891733': 'value2'}
d_keys = list(d.keys())

bound_names = ["lower bound", "upper bound"]
bounds = []
for i in range (0, 2):
    while True:
        try:
            bound = float(input("Enter the {} number: ".format(bound_names[i])))
        except ValueError:
            print("Number not entered.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    bounds.append(bound)

for n in range(len(d_keys)):
    if bounds[0] <= d_keys[n] <= bounds[1]:
        print(d[d_keys[n]])
```

If 38 (lower bound) and 38.3 (upper bound) are entered `value1` is printed.

Alternatively you can have search for numbers based on the part before the decimal:

```
d = {'38.1003827193': 'value1', '58.29932891733': 'value2'}    
d_keys = list(d.keys())

bound_names = [["lower bound", "inclusive"], ["upper bound", "exclusive"]]
bounds = []
for n in range(0, 2):
    while True:
        try:
            number_to_search = int(input("Enter {} number ({}): ".format(bound_names[n][0], bound_names[n][1])))
        except ValueError:
            print("Integer not entered.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    bounds.append(number_to_search)

for n in range(len(d_keys)):
    if int(d_keys[n]) in range(bounds[0], bounds[1]):
        print(d[d_keys[n]])
```

When 37 (lower bound) and 39 (upper bound) are entered the code prints: `value1`, but when 38 is entered as upper bound `value1` is not printed.

If you dont want it to print you can  have it return a list of all the values that are that number. 
All you would have to do is change the `print(d[d_keys[n]])` to `numbers_in_range.append(d[d_keys[n]])` and adding `numbers_in_range = []` somewhere above.